# MongoDB C# query performance much worse than mongotop reports

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have quite a bit of experience with Mongo, but am on the verge of tears of frustration about this problem (that of course popped up from nowhere a day before release).

Basically I am querying a database to retrieve a document but it will often be an order of magnitude (or even two) worse than it should be, particularly since the query is returning nothing.

Query:

```
//searchQuery ex: { "atomic.Basic^SessionId" : "a8297898-7fc9-435c-96be-9c5e60901e40" }
var doc = FindOne(searchQuery);
```

Explain:

```
{
   "cursor":"BtreeCursor atomic.Basic^SessionId",
   "isMultiKey" : false, 
   "   n":0,
   "nscannedObjects":0,
   "nscanned":0,
   "nscannedObjectsAllPlans":0,
   "nscannedAllPlans":0,
   "scanAndOrder":false,
   "indexOnly":false,
   "nYields":0,
   "nChunkSkips":0,
   "millis":0,
   "indexBounds":{
      "atomic.Basic^SessionId":[
         [
            "a8297898-7fc9-435c-96be-9c5e60901e40",
            "a8297898-7fc9-435c-96be-9c5e60901e40"
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

It is often taking 50-150 ms, even though mongotop reports at most 15 ms of read time (and that should be over several queries). There are only 6k documents in the database (only 2k or so are in the index, and the explain says it's using the index) and since the document being searched for isn't there, it can't be a deserialization issue.

It's not this bad on every query (sub ms most of the time) and surely the B-tree isn't large enough to have that much variance.

Any ideas will have my eternal gratitude.

Comment: Could it be some sort of threading issue? I deleted the database and it is still taking that much time even though there are no entries!

The collection is being called from a thread it wasn't created on, but calling a new GetCollection doesn't helper either.

Comment: If you are using windows, MongoDB is generally slower on Windows than other Operating Systems. As per the MongoDB C# driver, it's performance should be similar to other managed languages like Java (except if the query is strongly typed using generics then the performance might be very different). linq queries containing lambda expressions are also slower.

Comment: Are you measuring the 150ms at the wire level? (you can try wireshark or some network sniffer to see whether the query/response time is consumed from query end to query response at the tcp level , if not then it's your driver or application that is maybe imposing a delay?) Did you try the query in the shell? does it exhibit the same behavior? Does your experiment rely on a single query shot from "cold" app state? (may be related to establishing mongo server, replset connections etc for the first time)

Answer (score 0):

MongoTop is not reporting the total query time. It reports the amount of time MongoDB is spending holding particular locks.

That query retuned in 0ms according to the explain (which is extremely quickly). What you are describing sounds like network latency. What is the latency when you ping the node? Is it possible that the network is flakey?

What version of MongoDB are you using? Consider upgrading both MongoDB and the C# driver to the latest stable versions.